# Which iCloud service runs in background in OS X?

Tags: macos, icloud

I wondered which service is acutally updating the **MobileDocuments** folder in OS X?

I looked through the Apple Developer pages, but nowhere is any information about background services in OS X.

> When i save a file with TextEdit in the iCloud,the file is created in
>   the MobileDocuments folder. But how does it trigger the background
>   service?

Is there any information about those things yet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No it doesn't trigger to run any process.

Because the process is always running. The process for doing these kind of things is [`ubd`](http://www.macinside.info/process.php?name=ubd).

Click [here](http://www.macinside.info/process.php?name=ubd) for more information.

Comment: Another thing is that how `ubd` knows something is modified, my guess is folder watch. It has the file system tell it when anything in that folder is modified. If the applications that implement iCloud has to notify it about the changes, we wouldn't be able to use that folder as a Dropbox.